# Facebook sharing result is different than what is shown in debug tool

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a webpage for a journal where people should be able to share the articles on Facebook. The sharing itself is working, but the problem is the content of the shared post.

What I know is that I have to provide the right meta for the Facebook api to work properly. So that's what I've  done in PHP . It queries the database for the title, img source, description, etc... Then it fills those in `<meta>` tags. And I suppose the result is ok:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
<meta name="app_id" property="fb:app_id" content="1056245557765877">
        <meta name="ogtitle" property="og:title" content="اتفاقية تعاون لدعم طلاب الدكتوراه
    بين مجلس البحوث واللبنانية الاميركية">
<meta name="ogtype" property="og:type" content="article">
<meta name="ogurl" property="og:url" content="http://alanwar.com/article.php?categoryID=6&amp;articleID=296870">

<meta name="ogimage" property="og:image" content="http://alanwar.com/issues/2693/296870_55117_s.jpg ">


 <!--meta name="ogimage" property="og:image" content="#"/ -->
 <meta name="ogname" property="og:site_name" content="Alanwar">
 <meta name="ogdesc" property="og:description" content="وقعت الجامعة اللبنانية الأميركية (LAU) والمجلس الوطني للبحوث العلمية اتفاقية تعاون، في إطار دعم بعض الطلاب المتفوقين لدرجة الدكتوراه، ويتم التعاون بين الطرفين من خلال مركز الدراسات العليا والأبحاث في ...">
```

This is online , and I made sure the meta is written before the body is loading. Also here is the output from Facebook debug tool found [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/)

```
Meta Tag    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1056245557765877" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="&#x627;&#x62a;&#x641;&#x627;&#x642;&#x64a;&#x629; &#x62a;&#x639;&#x627;&#x648;&#x646; &#x644;&#x62f;&#x639;&#x645; &#x637;&#x644;&#x627;&#x628; &#x627;&#x644;&#x62f;&#x6... See More
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="http://alanwar.com/article.php?categoryID=6&amp;articleID=296870" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://alanwar.com/issues/2693/296870_55117_s.jpg " />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Alanwar" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:description" content="&#x648;&#x642;&#x639;&#x62a; &#x627;&#x644;&#x62c;&#x627;&#x645;&#x639;&#x629; &#x627;&#x644;&#x644;&#x628;&#x646;&#x627;&#x646;&#x64a;&#x629; &#x627;&#x644;&#x623... See More
```

(Content copied form the debug page)

And the shared post in the debugger is displaying just like I want it to.
Now when I click share on the webpage for a real test, it only shares a link, no title, no image ... Although I think I followed the proper procedure.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Whatever script you are using for sharing, it passes the wrong parameters to the FB sharer – it neglects to properly URL-encode the value.

Comment: @CBroe I tried adding a test button and put a simple script from Facebook developers `FB.ui` ... I get the popup to share , but still the content is wrong

Comment: What is the code for the share button?  Try copy-pasting your URL directly into the status field on Facebook, without clicking "post", it will load the preview right there.  If it works there, the problem is with the sharer button code on your site.  Also, I doubt it is a problem but you don't need a name for your [open graph tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters).

Comment: Try using `og:locale` [og sharing webmasters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)